# Multiple Tables for a single class in JDO (GWT)

Tags: gwt, jdo

I have a class of data that I am persisting using JDO on GWT and have a requirement for storing two sets of the same classes separately, one set is raw data and the other amalgamated and processed.
Is there an easy way to do this, have tried to find it in the docs with no luck.

Thanks, 
Aron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Neither JDO or JPA would support such a thing. Obviously you could subclass the class and have the subclass for the amalgamated/processed data and store it in its own table

Comment: Thanks very much, I wondered whether that would be the case.  With the subclassing, I can see a couple of mechanisms, for instance  class processedData extends RawData as one mechanism or class processedData extends BaseData and class RawData extends BaseData as another.  Any thoughts on merits of either approach?

Comment: Given that there are a number of ways of doing this which dont work very well, following is one way which I have got to work.

Answer (score 1):

As an update, given that there are a number of ways of attempting to subclass or embed the data within another class, lots of which dont work very well (on GWT), here are two schema that do work. In the first the main features are that primary key is in base class, and the inheritance strategy is SUBCLASS_TABLE. Note this means that BaseData cannot be persisted. A second mechanism is shown below.  In it the base class is a regular class that can be persisted and the derived class has an inheritance strategy of customStrategy="complete-table"

1)

```
@PersistenceCapable

@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)

public class BaseData  
{
    @PrimaryKey

    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    // scan data
    @Persistent
    public String Data1 = "";
    //  etc...
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class ProcessedData  extends BaseData
{
    // No key
    // Thats it
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class RawData  extends BaseData
{
    // No key
    // Thats it
}
```

2)

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(customStrategy = "complete-table")

public class ProcessedData  extends RawData 
{
// thats it
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class RawData 
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Persistent
    public String Data1 = "";

    // ...
}
```